# Side Effects in Python

Tags: python

I read this in the python docs: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

> requiring global for assigned variables provides a bar against
>   unintended side-effects.

Let's put this in code:

```
def double(n):
  global y 
  y = 2 * n # this turns global as we have state y explicitly global

y = 5 
double(y)
print y # outputs 10
```

I would like to double check my understanding if the above code has a side effect at global y if so 
I feel this is contradictory to the statement in the docs, basically I think requiring global for assigned variables does not guard against side effects.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted but I found it informative and in line with guidelines.  Genuinely curious as there's not great consistency on SO regarding what is seen as a good Q

Comment: Thank you :) I was curious to know what I was missing. Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Requiring global for assigned variables provides a bar against
>   unintended side-effects.

When the docs say that global *provides a bar against unintended* side-effects, it means that it safeguards you against situations where a function could change its outer scope because of name aliasing.

Here is an example:

```
x = 5

def safedouble(x)
    x = 2 * x
    return x

def unsafedouble(x)
    global x
    x = 2 * x
    return x

print(x) # 5
print(safedouble(x)) # 10
print(x) # 5 The x inside of the function does not interfere with x outside =)
print(unsafedouble(x)) # 10
print(x) # 10 ... do we really want this to happen?!
```

Requiring global means that functions only mutate the outer scope if the programmer explicitly asks for it.

Answer (score 3):

No, you misunderstand. Here is what the docs state in context:

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are
>   implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within
>   the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly
>   declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains
>   this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a
>   bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was
>   required for all global references, you’d be using global all the
>   time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in
>   function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would
>   defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying
>   side-effects.

Assignment to a name *does not require `global`*. You *can* use assignment without `global`, but the docs are telling you that if you do  use assignment in a local scope without the `global` directive, the name will be considered a local variable by default! The reasoning is as stated, if assigned-to variables inside a function could be global by default, then you might accidentally assign to a global variable and *inadvertently cause a side-effect*. But if you require a `global` directive, then you will know that your function produces a side-effect. It isn't stating that `global` *prevents* side-effects, it prevents *inadvertent side-effects*.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this situation, with different people writing different parts of the code.

```
def func1(n):
    y = n+1
    print y

... many lines of code

def func2(a)
    return y * a

... many lines of code
y = 7
... many lines of code
func1(50)
... many lines
print func2(100)
```

Without explicit `global` declarations, the `y` variable in `func1` is tied to the overall `y`, and the output of `func2(100)` is 5100 instead of the expected 700: the side effect of `func1` is a surprise to the writer of `func2`.

Explicit global declarations protect the external value from inadvertent changes to what the writer of `func1` intended to be a local, temporary variable.